# SQL query to find Sum of Amount from table Totals for all IDs for only Maximum Amounts

Tags: mysql

`Totals` table is

```
ID|Amount 
1|10
1|20
2|30
2|40
3|50
4|60
5|70
5|80
```

Tried below SQL query to find `sum` of `Amount` from table `Totals` for all `ID`s for only Maximum Amounts:

```
select SUM(Amount) from Totals
where ID in (select Max(ID) from Totals
group by ID
order by ID desc);
```

Comment: Try using rowid in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery that gets the maximum amount for each ID, then sum it.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as totalMax
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(amount) AS amount
    FROM Totals
    GROUP BY ID
) AS x
```